# How do we secure a Firebase Firestore without using Firestore Authentication? Or is it a must?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

At this moment we have 1 Firebase Function running that connects to a Firestore database instance.  It correctly connects to the Firestore database using the rules below, however this is **insecure**.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

**It is however unknown to me how we should secure this if we don't have Users in our application.** It is not multitenant. We just do HTTP calls to the function and it saves something in the database.

> To build user-based and role-based access systems that keep your users' data safe, use Firebase Authentication with Firebase Security Rules.

We do not have user data.

> Note: The server client libraries bypass all Cloud Firestore Security Rules and instead authenticate through Google Application Default Credentials.

If we change our write rule to **write: if request.auth() != null** our application fails to save.

However, we can call **getAuth()** and then **signInAnonymously()**. But how does that make it more secure? And how long will the function remain authenticated?

We have read the documentation at https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth and https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started. But as we don't have users in our application, it seems unclear to us how to secure Firestore using firestore.rules.

Concrete: How do we secure a Firebase Firestore without using Firestore Authentication? Or is it a must?

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you're only accessing Firestore via a Cloud Function? You never retrieve data from Firestore directly from the client?

Comment: @b2m9 indeed, only our Cloud Function connects to the Firestore Database using initializeApp(config). We don't have anything else connected to it.

Comment: Can you give some context on what collection you have and what can your users access?

Comment: I doubt that you access Firestore via Cloud Functions, because `firebase-admin/firestore` bypasses security rules entirely (as you state yourself from the docs).

Comment: @Dharmaraj We have a simple collection called Mappings (internal_id/external_id). Our Cloud Function has 2 HTTP endpoints, one saves a mapping and the other one returns a mapping.

Comment: And what are you trying to secure here? Like users can read external ID of a specific internal ID or so? or can users access anything>?

Comment: @b2m9 Hmm indeed, when connecting as admin it does make sense request.auth is null. So maybe that's why the rules block the Function. However I would think it would bypass that entirely...

Comment: @Dharmaraj the only client that performs HTTP requests to our Function is another Function. So the one Function connected to Firestore will only get requests from 1 client and no users.

Comment: @Sacagaweja Rules do not block requests when using the server-side libraries. They're not even invoked.

Answer (score 2):

When not using Firebase Authentication, you cannot get details of user who is making the request. [`request.auth`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth) will be `null` in this case and hence `request.auth() != null` fails.

When you use `signInAnonymously()` the user is signed in with Firebase Auth and `request.auth` contains details of that user. However, once the user logs out of an anonymous account by any mean, there is no way to log back in with that account and user won't be able to access their data again.

If you use your own authentication method, using Cloud functions to retrieve data would be best so you can authenticate user using your auth system and then serve data if authorized.